# How to fix command node issue while building android app with react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-redux, react-native

I am using react-native and updated android studio to 3.0. After updating while trying to debug on a device I am getting a build error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'node''
```

I have stopped and rerun the gradle but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 9):

`./gradlew --stop` and then start the build your project again.

Comment: Thanks! Any explanation why this worked?

Comment: can't believe it is working

Comment: it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just got this error myself. Actually, just close Android Studio when doing ./gradlew assembleDebug in your cmd. It just blocks gradle node execution somehow.

Comment: Wow, who could have guessed this :O